# How to find 5th character in a given string(column data) in SQL or PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a column in a table say ENAME, I need to find out 5th                             character in every value. In other words how to find 5th character in given string in SQL, PL/SQL....

Comment: What should happen if the value in your field is less than 5 characters long?

Comment: in that case should print null

Answer (score 2):

Use the substring function:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(fieldname, 5,1)
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the LEFT 5 then RIGHT 1 of those results?  You'll need to append some character if the string is less than 5 characters or take the right most character if it's less than 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give null when your field is less than 5 characters then solution of Goat Co is perfect. But you can always replace it with your suitable string to notify you.

see below:

```
    with tab as
    (
    select 'Apple' ename from dual
    union all
    select 'Detail' from dual
    union all
    select 'cat'  from dual
    )
    select NVL(substr(ename,5,1), 'NA') from tab;
```